# How to retrieve the session ID from Spring Websocket on initial handshake and to be used later on?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

How to retrieve the session ID from Spring Websocket on initial handshake and to be used later on?

**Goal**
The Goal is whenever a Websocket client connects to the websocket server. The websocket client will pass in a parameter. It will pass in their tenantID. Upon successfull connection to the websocket server. The websocket server usually generates a session ID. What I hope to achieve is associate this websocket sessionID to that specific tenant parameter. And later on, whenever a websocket server will send an update to the that client/tenant. it will send it to that specific tenant via its sessionID that the websocket server has created.

Here is my websocket server configuration..

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/queue");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }


    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        //registry.addEndpoint("/client").addInterceptors(new WSHandshakeInterceptor()).withSockJS();
        registry.addEndpoint("/agent").addInterceptors(new WSHandshakeInterceptor()).withSockJS();
    }
}
```

**WSHandhsakeInterceptor.java**

```
public class WSHandshakeInterceptor implements HandshakeInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest, ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse, WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler, Map<String, Object> map) throws Exception {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest, ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse, WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler, Exception e) {
        HttpHeaders header = serverHttpRequest.getHeaders();
        String client = header.get("client-id").get(0);
        String sessionId = null;
        if (serverHttpRequest instanceof ServletServerHttpRequest) {
            ServletServerHttpRequest servletRequest = (ServletServerHttpRequest) serverHttpRequest;
            HttpSession session = servletRequest.getServletRequest().getSession();
            sessionId = session.getId();
            System.out.println("Session ID + "+sessionId);
            System.out.println("CLIENT ID "+client);
            ClassChangeNotificationServiceImpl.clientSessionMap.put(client, sessionId);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how my websocket client connects to the server.

```
WebSocketClient simpleWebSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();
        List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>(1);
        transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(simpleWebSocketClient));
        SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);
        stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
        String url = "ws://localhost:8081/agent";
        sessionHandler = new MyStompSessionHandler();
        try {
            WebSocketHttpHeaders wsHTTPheaders = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();
            wsHTTPheaders.add("CLIENT-ID","XXXTESTCLIENTXXX");
            session = stompClient.connect(url, wsHTTPheaders,sessionHandler).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**MyStompSessionHandler.java**

```
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompFrameHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSession;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSessionHandlerAdapter;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class  MyStompSessionHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {

    private void subscribeTopic(String topic, StompSession session) {
        session.subscribe(topic, new StompFrameHandler() {
            @Override
            public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {

                System.out.println("HANDLER");
                return String.class;
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
                System.out.println("TEST HEKHEk");
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
        return String.class;
    }

    /**
     * This implementation is empty.
     */
    @Override
    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
        String resp = (String) payload;
        System.out.println("Received responses from websocket server: "+ resp);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
        subscribeTopic("/user/queue/response", session);

        System.out.println("CONNECTEd");
        for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry: connectedHeaders.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+"S");
        }
    }
}
```

Now For the fun part. or what I've been trying to achieve. is I can send an update to the websocket client via this code

```
this.template.convertAndSendToUser(client, "/queue/reply", message);
```

Where client is the sessionID that spring has generated. and it will send a message to that specific client only

**Question**
How do I retrieve the sessionID after a successful handshake?? can I use this sessionID to send specific updates to that client. Here's my code..

Answer (score 0):

Just add this method anywhere in your code to get the session ID after handshake:

```
@EventListener
    private void handleSessionConnected(SessionConnectEvent event) {
        String sessionId = SimpAttributesContextHolder.currentAttributes().getSessionId();
    }
```